# Rails radio_buttons multiple selection for same attribute, is it possible?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, search, ransack

I have a `search_form_for` and I need to be able to select multiple Payment `status`es to make a Ransack search.

We already have an `f.select` dropdown box for this attribute, but we now need to be able to select more than one `status` at the same time.

*form:*

```
<%= search_form_for @search, url: admin_payments_path, html: {class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.select :status_eq, payment_status_selector, { include_blank: "Payment status.."}, class: "form-control gray" %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

I've tried:

```
<%= f.select :status_eq, payment_status_selector, {include_blank: false}, {multiple: true, as: :radio_buttons}  %>
```

gives me a select box with all the options allowing me to select multiple, but they are not `radio_buttons` and an empty value `""` is passed along with the selected options.

```
    <% payment_status_selector.each do |status| %>
      <%= radio_button_tag :status_eq, "#{status[1]}", false,  class: 'radio-checkbox' %>
      <%= label_tag( "#{status[0]}") %>
    <% end %>
```

This gives me a `radio_button` for each possible `status`, but I can't select more than one.

I can't figure out the correct way to do it. Maybe with `check_boxes` are a better option to be able to select/unselect statuses?

Comment: In this case searchbox is better and convenient (UX).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? How could I select multiple statuses from a search box? @zswqa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using check_box will be a better option.

Try,

```
<% payment_status_selector.each do |status| %>
  <%= f.check_box :payment_statuses, { multiple: true }, status, false %>
  <%= label status %>
<% end %>
```

And you can expect the values in controller from params as:

> { search: { payment_statuses: ["status 1", "status 2"] }

make sure that `payment_status_selector` returns array of values.

Hope that helped.

Reference: https://medium.com/programming-problem-solving-logbook/rails-multiple-checkboxes-e9c4c7fda356